# on Change não starta após o trigger();

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_scripts/_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<input type='hidden' id='idSetor' name='idSetor' value=1/>

<script>
    $( function () {

        $( "#idSetor" ).trigger( "change" );

    } );
</script>

<script>
    $( document ).ready( function ( e ) {

        $( "#idSetor" ).on( "change", function () {

            if ( $( "#idSetor" ).val() != "" ) {

                $.ajax( {
                    url: "_scripts/_php/_contagens/contaCelulas.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        idCelula: $( "#idSetor" ).val()
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $( "#imgCarregando" ).css( 'display', 'block' );
                    },
                    success: function ( result ) {

                        $( "#imgCarregando" ).css( 'display', 'none' );

                        if ( result >= 4 ) {
                            $( "#conta" ).html( "<h1>Esse Setor já possui " + result + " Células!</h1>" );
                            $( "#conta" ).css( "display", "block" );
                            $( "#escolhaCelula" ).css( "display", "none" );
                        } else {
                            $( "#conta" ).css( "display", "none" );
                            $( "#escolhaCelula" ).css( "display", "block" );
                        }

                    }

                } );

            } else {
                $( "#conta" ).html( "<h1>Escolha a Rede!</h1>" );
                $( "#conta" ).css( "display", "block" );
                $( "#escolhaCelula" ).css( "display", "none" );
            }


        } );

    } );
</script>

<div id="conta"></div>

<div id="escolhaCelula" style="display: none;">
    <label class="labelPequeno" for="nome">Nome da Célula</label> : <input type="text" class="inputTextMedio required" name="nome" id="nome" required/><br/><br/>
    <button id="buttonCadastrarCelula" class="button">Cadastrar</button>
    <img id="imgCarregando" style="display: none" src="_imgs/carregando.gif"/><br/>
</div>

<div class="resposta"></div>
```

Gostaria de saber porque, após o

```
$( "#idSetor" ).trigger( "change" );
```

a função

```
$( "#idSetor" ).on( "change", function () {}
```

Não roda?

Isto é, não entra no `onchange`

Comment: O `$( "#idSetor" ).on( "change", function () {}` está vindo depois do trigger. Assim o trigger ainda não conheceu o evento que está tentando disparar.

Comment: existe allguma forma de eu chamar o trigger antes da função?

Comment: Na base da gambiarra tem: `$( function () {
   setTimeout(function(){
      $( "#idSetor" ).trigger( "change" );
   }, 100);
});`.... o trigger será disparado 1 décimo de segundo após o carregamento da página.

Comment: tenho uma validação do form que, conforme a situação, o campo idSetor, precisa ser  escolhido numa select e dependendo ele é carregado junto com a página em um input hidden. Será que existe uma forma de conferir de onde está vindo o valor do idSetor? Se vem de um Select ou de um Input Hidden antes de chamar o trigger()?

Comment: `$("#idSetor").prop("tagName")`... o valor será INPUT ou SELECT (em caixa alta mesmo)

Comment: if ( $( "#idSetor" ).attr('type') == "hidden" ) $("#idSetor").trigger("change");

Comment: .prop("tagName") é melhor?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88692/discussion-between-sam-and-carlos-rocha).